# Using bool type in Proto-Buf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net in my application for serializaion/deserialization. I am facing an issue.

```
[ProtoContract()]
ClsTest
{
    private bool _isPeriodic

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public bool IsPeriodic
    {
        get
        {
             return _isPeriodic;
        }

        set
        {
            isPeriodic = value;
        }
   }

}
```

I am using this class in my collction object.

The serialization process workes fine, but after deserialization the Value for property IsPeriodic by default is true eventhough it was false for some cases. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that your code is setting `IsPeriodic` to `true` for default `new` instances, perhaps:

```
private bool _isPeriodic = true;
```

or, in the constructor you have:

```
_isPeriodic = true; // or IsPeriodic = true
```

*Basically*, there is an implicit default (following the protobuf language guide) where-by bool is assumed to have a default of `false`. It doesn't send data that is believed to be the default. If this default is incorrect, tell it:

```
[ProtoMember(1), DefaultValue(true)]
```

or IIRC you can try setting `IsRequired` to `true` instead:

```
[ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
```

and there are a few other ways of telling it to always send the value:

```
private bool ShouldSerializeIsPeriodic() { return true;}
```

(which uses the same pattern that is supported by core .NET for `PropertyGrid`, `XmlSerializer`, `PropertyDescriptor`, etc - it isn't me inventing random patterns)

Note that in "v2" I have made two further changes to help remove this oddity:

- you can optionally bypass the constructor (WCF-style)
- the new meta-model provides *another* way of deciding whether or not to assume a default

Answer (score 1):

I found working with bool and enum type with protobuf-net has some tricks.
The first issue about default value for both bool and enum type:
Here's my Linq snippet code:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyOption
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public View m_printListView = View.Details;   (A)
    [ProtoMember(5) ]
    public bool m_bool = true ;                   (B)
}

void Main()
{
    string fname = @"D:/test.dat";
    if (File.Exists(fname) )
    {
        File.Delete(fname);
    }
    using(FileStream fs=  new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write) )
    {
        MyOption opt = new MyOption();
        opt.m_printListView = View.LargeIcon; // (1)
        opt.m_bool = false;                   // (2)

        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(fs, opt, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
    }
    using(FileStream fs=  new FileStream(@"D:/test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) )
    {
        MyOption opt;
        opt = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<MyOption>(fs, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
        Console.WriteLine(opt.m_printListView);
        Console.WriteLine(opt.m_bool);
    }
}
```

Now, guess the output. It's:

```
Details
True
```

Note that in (A) and (B) I set default value to View.Details and true.
In (1) And (2) I explicitly set the value to View.LargeIcon and false, after proto-buf's serialization and
de-serialization, we got the wrong value.

The reason is that: for bool value, the default value is false, according to proto-buf's design principle, it will save space when possible, so default value is not saved in the file, only a flag is saved to indicate should use default value(I guess, not verified).

When de-serialization, at first the default constructor is called, and lines (B) is actually part of default constructor at CLR runtime, then the proto-buf de-serialization process kicks up, and found the member m_bool has a default value flag, then use the default value false to set m_bool,  which overwrite the default value at (B).

For enum type the reason is similar, in the above example View.LargeIcon is the default value, whose numeric value is 0(verified by Reflected).

To fix it using the DefaultValueAttribute for bool and enum member:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MyOption
{
    [ProtoMember(2), DefaultValue(View.Details)]
    public View m_printListView = View.Details;   (A)
    [ProtoMember(5), DefaultValue(true) ]
    public bool m_bool = true ;                   (B)
}
```

For enum type, there're other issues:
The first one is that all the enumerator should have distinct values, otherwise proto-buf will throw exception when serialization, e.g., the System.Drawing.RotateFlip enum type has following definition:

```
    public enum RotateFlipType
{
    Rotate180FlipNone = 2,
    Rotate180FlipX = 6,
    Rotate180FlipXY = 0,
    Rotate180FlipY = 4,
    Rotate270FlipNone = 3,
    Rotate270FlipX = 7,
    Rotate270FlipXY = 1,
    Rotate270FlipY = 5,
    Rotate90FlipNone = 1,
    Rotate90FlipX = 5,
    Rotate90FlipXY = 3,
    Rotate90FlipY = 7,
    RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,
    RotateNoneFlipX = 4,
    RotateNoneFlipXY = 2,
    RotateNoneFlipY = 6
}
```

From image processing's point, RotateNoneFlipNone and Rotate180FlipXY has the same effect, so they have
the same underlying value, it's a reasonable design, however, such a enum cannot works with proto-buf:

```
    The enum System.Drawing.RotateFlipType has conflicting values RotateNoneFlipNone and RotateNoneFlipNone
Serializer.ThrowInner (Exception exception)
  at ProtoBuf.Serializer.ThrowInner(Exception exception)
  at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance)
  at ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix[T](Stream destination, T instance, PrefixStyle style, Int32 tag)
```

My workaround is to create my own enum and use one-to-one mapping between My_RotateFlipType and System.Drawing.RotateFlipType. Only My_RotateFlipType will be serialized by proto-buf.

```
public enum RotateFlipType              public enum My_RotateFlipType
{                                       {
    Rotate180FlipNone = 2,                  Rotate180FlipNone,
    Rotate180FlipX = 6,                     Rotate180FlipX,
    Rotate180FlipXY = 0,                    Rotate180FlipXY,
    Rotate180FlipY = 4,                     Rotate180FlipY,
    Rotate270FlipNone = 3,                  Rotate270FlipNone,
    Rotate270FlipX = 7,                     Rotate270FlipX,
    Rotate270FlipXY = 1,                    Rotate270FlipXY,
    Rotate270FlipY = 5,                     Rotate270FlipY,
    Rotate90FlipNone = 1,                   Rotate90FlipNone,
    Rotate90FlipX = 5,                      Rotate90FlipX,
    Rotate90FlipXY = 3,                     Rotate90FlipXY,
    Rotate90FlipY = 7,                      Rotate90FlipY,
    RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,                 RotateNoneFlipNone,
    RotateNoneFlipX = 4,                    RotateNoneFlipX,
    RotateNoneFlipXY = 2,                   RotateNoneFlipXY,
    RotateNoneFlipY = 6                     RotateNoneFlipY
}                                       }
```

To avoid manually sync with the two data members, I use ProtoBeforeSerialization and OnProtoAfterDeserialization feature to automate it:

```
[ProtoAfterDeserialization()]
public void OnProtoAfterDeserialization()
{
    Console.WriteLine("called OnProtoAfterDeserialization");
    bool ret = Enum.TryParse(m_rotate.ToString(), out m_rotate_protobuf);
}

[ProtoBeforeSerialization()]
public void OnProtoBeforeSerialization()
{
    Console.WriteLine("called OnProtoBeforeSerialization");
    bool ret = Enum.TryParse(m_rotate_protobuf.ToString(), out m_rotate);
}
```

The second issue about enum is the 0-value enumerator. If an enum has no enumerator with value 0, then
it's very easy for protobuf to throw exception at runtime.

I will follow the rules when working with protobuf-net:
1. Whenever the default constructor set a value other than default value, use the DefaultValueAttribute.
2. For system or third-party enum type, check it with reflector (statically) or linq (runtime) to see whether it has the above issue, before you add it to protobuf. If conflicts, use the above workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me:

```
[ProtoContract]
class ClsTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public bool IsPeriodic { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
   // stream is a NetworkStream object

   ClsTest clsTestObj = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ClsTest>(stream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
   bool value = clsTestObj.IsPeriodic;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar issue, where `bool` members that default to `true` were not reading their value from the config file.

```
[ProtoMember(1, IsRequired=true), DefaultValue(true)]
public bool IsPeriodic
...
```