# Serializing Booleans with ProtoBuf-NET

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a class that holds information regarding a sound file. Path, volume and such. These objects are stored in a ObservableCollection, which is then serialized/deserialized.

What has me thrown off is that, from what I can tell - every single property is properly serialized and deserialized *except* for the bools.

I've read various answers on here that mentions the use of `ProtoInclude`, `IsRequired` or `DefaultValue` but no matter which of these I use - I get the exact same result.

For example, this is how I've set up my parameters;

```
// Serialized Variables
[ProtoMember(1)]
public string FilePath { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(2)]
public string Category { get; set; }
[ProtoMember(3)]
public List<string> Tags { get; set; } = new List<string>();
[ProtoMember(4)]
public double TransmitVolume { get; set; } = 0.75;
[ProtoMember(5)]
public double ListenVolume { get; set; } = 0.50;
[ProtoMember(6, IsRequired = true)]
public bool Listen { get; set; } = true;
[ProtoMember(7, IsRequired = true)]
public bool Repeat { get; set; } = false;
```

Serialized and deserialized like so *(using OpenWrite + OpenRead respectively)*;

```
Serializer.Serialize(file, _observableSounds);
Serializer.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<SoundFile>>(file);
```

The 2 bools will *always* be their default values, the other parameters are properly updated if I make any changes.

It may be worth mentioning that the serialization happens via a static class, which implements a `Save` and `Load` method.

To further visualize what is going on, I have a custom user control that contains a little control panel like this;
[image]

The first 2 buttons represent the **Listen** and **Repeat** properties. If I for example, toggle listen *off* and repeat *on* and save the changes, close and reload - the changes are ignored and defaults are loaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Rather than `Listen = true`, I would suggest `bool? _listen; Listen { get => _listen ?? true; ...` so you can tell the difference between constructed / serialised values.

Comment: You probably need `[DefaultValue(true)]', since otherwise only true values would be written. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162253/4139809

Comment: I've tried that along with IsRequired but as I said in the OP, the results are the same even with one of these or both of them. Do note that even if I try and switch `Repeat` to true, which is false by default - still reverts to false upon saving and then reloading.

Comment: Something seems very odd here. Bools should work fine. I can look, but: what library version are you using, out of curiosity?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've got the latest as far as I'm aware, 3.0.101. Most likely I am doing something wrong, I'm just not entirely sure what - still somewhat new to .NET and don't know all the do's and don'ts :)

I've made my repo public in case that helps, you can find it at Dealman/Streamster, it's in a refactor stage atm so it's kind of messy at the moment.

Comment: @Dealman thanks; I'll try to take a look this weekend, chores allowing (I'm the author of protobuf-net)

Comment: @MarcGravell Cheers, appreciate it - take your time :). I've been considering using JSON instead, but I really like ProtoBuf so will continue and fiddle around to see if I can figure out what I'm doing wrong meanwhile.

And I'm well aware, seen you pop up in pretty much every single protobuf related question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem here is using `File.OpenWrite` to overwrite an existing file; if the new file you write is *shorter*, `File.OpenWrite` *does not automatically truncate* - which can leave additional data at the end of the file. This additional data *might* cause an exception, or *might* be interpreted as additional fields to process (since protobuf is designed such that append===merge). If using `File.OpenWrite`, you need to manually call `.SetLength(...)` to truncate it - however, it is easier and more correct so simply use `File.Create` instead.

The following, based on the code in the question, works via files and works entirely correctly:

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

Show(true, true, "abcde");
Show(true, false, "abcd");
Show(false, true, "abc");
Show(false, false, "ab");

static void Show(bool listen, bool repeat, string filePath)
{
    SomeType obj = new SomeType { Listen = listen, Repeat = repeat, FilePath = filePath }, clone;
    const string path = "my.bin";

    // serialize to file
    using (var file = File.Create(path))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(file, obj);
        Console.WriteLine($"Serialized: {file.Position} bytes");
    }

    // normally wouldn't do this; just be lazy to show contents
    var payload = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {payload.Length} bytes: {BitConverter.ToString(payload)}");

    // deserialize from file
    using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        clone = Serializer.Deserialize<SomeType>(file);
    }

    // show how well we did (or didn't)
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(clone.Listen)}: {clone.Listen} vs {listen}, {nameof(clone.Repeat)}: {clone.Repeat} vs {repeat}\t{(clone.Repeat == repeat && clone.Listen == listen ? "Pass" : "Fail")}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

[ProtoContract]
class SomeType
{
    // Serialized Variables
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public double TransmitVolume { get; set; } = 0.75;
    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public double ListenVolume { get; set; } = 0.50;
    [ProtoMember(6, IsRequired = true)]
    public bool Listen { get; set; } = true;
    [ProtoMember(7, IsRequired = true)]
    public bool Repeat { get; set; } = false;
}
```

---

Note that the other approach, of using `[DefaultValue]` instead of `IsRequired`, also works entirely correctly:

```cs
    [ProtoMember(6), DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Listen { get; set; } = true;
    [ProtoMember(7), DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Repeat { get; set; } = false;
```

---

If this doesn't help, a similar example to the above that demonstrates the problem would be very useful.

Comment: Hmm, then I am probably doing something wrong. Do you think me trying to serialize a static ObservableCollection containing my custom type could be the cause? I'll try and whip up a proper repo project sometime tomorrow. Should I update OP, or comment here?

Comment: @Dealman maybe both? An edit to the OP is probably necessary because of size, but I won't get notified of that automatically - but if you comment here: I will be :)

Comment: Since my project is way overdue a refactor/cleanup, I decided to start fresh and start with implementing my DataGrid, AudioFile & AudioLibrary classes to see if I could narrow down what caused the issue. This time it worked as intended right away, and my implementation is pretty much identical. I have not been able to reproduce the issue yet... :(